# How do threads get handled?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Am I getting it right, that if you have for example four CPU's and four threads, these are getting distributed on each CPU? And when you have got five threads, one CPU has to handle two threads at once?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In theory, yes.  In practice, you could have a single CPU that has all of the threads assigned to it, multiple CPUs that have more than one thread and others with none ... or any combination in between.

Comment: There are no guarantees.  Your operating system can do whatever it wants with your threads.

Comment: Threads do not necessarily model parallelism: they model *logical* concurrency, not *actual* concurrency. When you have multiple threads, you tell the OS that you have things that you want to do at the same time (logically). It can take those instructions and try to run them by splitting them up to different CPUs. But some processors can also do things like, if a operation will take 10 cycles to complete, start it and do an operation from a different thread while its running ("hyperthreading"). Or a dumb system could run 1 thread to completion before starting the work on the next.

Comment: If the threads are not in the running state, none of them are distributed on any CPU.

Answer (score 2):

The only guarantee you get is that the threads will run independently of each other. Scheduling is done by the operating system and the OS usually tries to make all cores busy, but since there is a lot more running on your computer than just your program, there's no guarantee that your four threads will always run on the four cores.

On Windows, you can pin threads to a processor core, but this is neither standard nor cross-platform, and not always to the benefit of your program.

Comment: *and the OS usually tries to make all cores busy*: depends, on a laptop in "economic" mode it would be wasteful to wake up a core for just a couple instructions.